# Add text tpo headercell in Datagridview VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I am trying that every time a row is added in the datagridview, the HeaderCell of that row is renamed to the value that the user is going to enter. Something like this:

[image]

I am doing it with the following code:

Dim Color As String
Color = InputBox("Introduzca en nombre de la Nueva Color (Máx. 10 Caracteres.)")

```
DataGridView1.Rows(0).HeaderCell.Value = Color
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(Color)
```

But it works as follows:

[image]

the data that is in column 02 is what should go in the headercell of each row, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: DataGridView1.Rows(0).HeaderCell.Value will set the value on the first row only.  Do you mean to find the current/new row first maybe?  And I would put some thought into your variable naming.  Using keywords (eg Color) for variable names can get you in a little bit of a mess

Comment: Do you have any suggestion of how I could carry out the same procedure and make it the same as the first image by entering the data with an inputbox?

Comment: Is the DataGridView not data-bound? You cannot add rows like that if it is. If it's not bound, then just `dim newIndex = DataGridView1.Rows.Add() DataGridView1.Rows(newIndex).HeaderCell.Value = "SOMECOLOR"`. Otherwise, add a new Row to the datasource -- I don't think it's a good idea to set the Row Header like that, but it's your choice.